# JSP pagination from javabean

Tags: java, oracle, jsp

I am trying to do jsp pagination, I loooked all over but didnt find any example that shows the way I want to do it. In my program I am loading data from oracle table using package. I have a package that has procedure loaddata, which is called from javabean load function. Curently all the data are dumped to jsp page from javabean, some one has a example I can look at it to change it into multiple pages. Thank you

Where can I find JSP pagination examples?

Comment: Please make it a question. Also, I'm not really sure what you mean by pagination. You may paginate simply by passing parameters to the page, and loading data according to the parameter.

Comment: First that google returns on "jsp pagination example": http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/paging.shtml

Comment: @Ondra: Roseindia.net is the *worst* source of Java EE examples. They are cluttered with bad practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and simple answer, use this:

http://www.datatables.net/

It's a lovely scrollable/paginating table, which has third party plugins which allow editing.  It's pretty easy to setup, and the website has lots of examples and an active and helpful forum.

From a database perspective, you'll need to consider accepting the following parameters to your queries:

1. Rows per page
2. Current page

The DBA in my company splits this into two queries I need to call:

1. Give me all the values for page 1, with 10 rows per page.
2. Give me the maximum number of pages that are possible (don't actually return any values.)